# Vertically aligning a video in a table cell

Tags: html, css, video

I've been kicking myself for days over this; hopefully someone can help! I'm trying to vertically align a video in the middle of a fixed height cell. The overflow at the top and bottom should be hidden.

Here is my code up to now:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td height="500" style="display: block; overflow: hidden;">
    <div style="position: relative;">
      <video autoplay loop width="100%" style="display: block;">
        <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This renders with the overflow at the bottom hidden, but any attempt to vertically center it fails...

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Changing the styles for the `td` centeres the video vertically:

`style="vertical-align: middle; overflow: hidden;"`